# How do I dig out field data in the XML file using Python and ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to read XML data from a weathergoose device using Python and the ElementTree module.   I can get the "name" data from the 'device' node but I would like to read the data listed under the 'device' node.  In particular, I would like to have the value of "TempF"

Here is an example of the XML data:

```xml
<server host="WeatherGoose" address="10.0.0.11" <omited stuff> tempunit="F">
    <devices>
        <device id="0114BE53110000E6" name="WeatherGoose" type="WxGoos" available="1" index="0">
            <field key="TempC" value="20.55" niceName="Temperature (C)" min="-20" max="50" type="2"/>
            <field key="TempF" value="68.99" niceName="Temperature (F)" min="-4" max="122" type="2"/>
            <field key="Humidity" value="42.00" niceName="Relative Humidity" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="Airflow" value="33.27" niceName="Air Flow" min="0" max="100" type="2"/>
            <field key="Light" value="2.00" niceName="Light Level" min="1" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="Sound" value="30.00" niceName="Sound Level" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="IO1" value="99.00" niceName="Moisture" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="IO2" value="99.00" niceName="IO-2" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="IO3" value="0.00" niceName="Door Contacts" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
        </device>
    </devices>
</server>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```py
import os
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
  feed = urllib.urlopen("http://10.0.0.11/data.xml")

  try:
    tree = ET.parse(feed)    
    root = tree.getroot()    
    event = root.find("devices")

    for e in event:
      print e.attrib['name']

  except Exception, inst:
    print "Error: %s: %s" % (tree, inst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This produces the hostname of the device but I cannot find the magic to dig out the 'field key' data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does that print the device name when the find() is looking for "devices" which doesn't have any attributes? I also noticed `<omited stuff>` in the root element; you didn't remove anything like `xmlns` right?

Comment: The header above was just an example, I have no way to change the XML coming from the device.   As for the why the code works with 'devices', I have no answer.  If I change it to 'device' I get an error.Error: <xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x7f9b26b96990>: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Here is the complete header:

<server 
 host="WeatherGoose" address="10.0.0.11" 
 address-backup="10.0.0.11" 
 name="WxGoos-2" 
 version="2.76" 
 pversion="2.02" 
 mac-address="00:40:9D:2F:6A:79" 
 datetime="Fri, 19 Jul  1:27:21 PM" 
 company="I.T. Watchdogs, Inc." 
 company-url="http://www.itwatchdogs.com" 
 support-email="support@itwatchdogs.com" 
 support-phone="512.257.1462" 
 console-id="wxg" 
 buzzer="1" 
 tempunit="F"
>

Comment: Ahh I see. You're selecting "devices" as `event` and iterating over its children. "device" is a child and has a "name" attribute. I was only asking about xmlns because that would change how elements would be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to select the `field` element that has a `key` attribute with a value of `TempF` by using the xpath `field[@key='TempF']` (with the current element context being `device`).

Example (change `feed` back to your urllib call)...

```
def main():
    feed = "test.xml"  # Used an external file for testing.

    try:
        tree = ET.parse(feed)
        root = tree.getroot()
        devices = root.findall("devices/device")

        for device in devices:
            print device.get("name")
            print device.find("field[@key='TempF']").get("value")

    except Exception, inst:
        print "Error: %s" % inst
```

this will print:

```
WeatherGoose
68.99
```

Note: If you have more than one `device` element, this will iterate over each one.

Comment: Thank you!   This worked perfectly!   I don't think I would have ever figured that combination out.

Answer (score 0):

The code below iterate over the xml and populate a dict where the key is the device id and the value is a list of dicts. Each dict represents a 'field' attributes. Only fields that were defined as 'interesting' are collected.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pprint


xml = '''<server host="WeatherGoose" address="10.0.0.11"  tempunit="F">
    <devices>
        <device id="0114BE53110000E6" name="WeatherGoose" type="WxGoos" available="1" index="0">
            <field key="TempC" value="20.55" niceName="Temperature (C)" min="-20" max="50" type="2"/>
            <field key="TempF" value="68.99" niceName="Temperature (F)" min="-4" max="122" type="2"/>
            <field key="Humidity" value="42.00" niceName="Relative Humidity" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="Airflow" value="33.27" niceName="Air Flow" min="0" max="100" type="2"/>
            <field key="Light" value="2.00" niceName="Light Level" min="1" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="Sound" value="30.00" niceName="Sound Level" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="IO1" value="99.00" niceName="Moisture" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="IO2" value="99.00" niceName="IO-2" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
            <field key="IO3" value="0.00" niceName="Door Contacts" min="0" max="99" type="2"/>
        </device>
    </devices>
</server>
  '''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
result = {}
interesting_fields = ['Airflow','TempF']
devices = root.findall('.//devices/device')
for device in devices:
    result[device.attrib['id']] = [f.attrib for f in device.findall('./field') if f.attrib['key'] in interesting_fields]

pprint.pprint(result)
```

output

```
{'0114BE53110000E6': [{'key': 'TempF',
                       'max': '122',
                       'min': '-4',
                       'niceName': 'Temperature (F)',
                       'type': '2',
                       'value': '68.99'},
                      {'key': 'Airflow',
                       'max': '100',
                       'min': '0',
                       'niceName': 'Air Flow',
                       'type': '2',
                       'value': '33.27'}]}
```